# How to log retries from Polly with ILoggerFactory

Tags: c#, logging, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.1, polly

Or: How to log from a static method.

From https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly you have examples like this one where a logger is magically available:

```
Policy
  .Timeout(30, onTimeout: (context, timespan, task) => 
    {
        logger.Warn($"{context.PolicyKey} at {context.ExecutionKey}: execution timed out after {timespan.TotalSeconds} seconds.");
    });
```

In my code I am using the new `IHttpClientFactory` pattern from dotnet core 2.1, and adding it like this in my Startup.cs `ConfigureServices` method:

```
    services.AddHttpClient<IMySuperHttpClient, MySuperHttpClient>()
        .AddPolicyHandler(MySuperHttpClient.GetRetryPolicy())
        .AddPolicyHandler(MySuperHttpClient.GetCircuitBreakerPolicy());
```

With the `GetRetryPolicy` being static and looking like this:

```
internal static IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> GetRetryPolicy()
{
    return HttpPolicyExtensions
        .HandleTransientHttpError()
        .OrResult(msg => msg.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(
            retryCount: 4,
            sleepDurationProvider: retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)),
            onRetry: OnRetry);
}
```

Where the `OnRetry` method aswell have to be static:

```
private static void OnRetry(DelegateResult<HttpResponseMessage> delegateResult, TimeSpan timespan, Context context)
{
    // var logger = ??
    // logger.LogWarning($"API call failed blah blah.");
}
```

How can you access an `ILoggerFactory` here, if at all possible?

Comment: You can pass any custom data into a Polly policy - including an `ILogger` or `ILoggerFactory` - using `Polly.Context`.  [This blog post](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/passing-an-ilogger-to-polly-policies) by Steve Gordon demonstrates how to pass an `ILogger` into a policy configured via IHttpClientFactory. The same principle can be applied for an `ILoggerFactory`.

Comment: Polly's HttpClientFactory documentation also now adds another example of [how to use an `ILogger<T>` with a policy on a typed client configured by HttpClientFactory](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory#configuring-policies-to-use-services-registered-with-di-such-as-iloggert)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it was stated in the comments by [mountain traveller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4151019/mountain-traveller) there are multiple ways to solve the issue:

- Use a `Context` to pass any arbitrary object between the `Execute(Async)` and `onRetry(Async)` delegate
- Use a different overload of `AddPolicyHandler`

The former solution requires an explicit call of `Execute` / `ExecuteAsync` to be able to provide a `Context` object which encapsulates an `ILogger` instance. In case of Named/Typed Http Client this route is not a viable option, since you decorate the whole `HttpClient` with a [`PolicyHttpMessageHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.http.policyhttpmessagehandler). So, not your code is the one which calls the `Execute(Async)` rather the Handler on your behalf.

The latter solution [provides access to the `IServiceProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.pollyhttpclientbuilderextensions.addpolicyhandler?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-pollyhttpclientbuilderextensions-addpolicyhandler(microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-ihttpclientbuilder-system-func((system-iserviceprovider-system-net-http-httprequestmessage-polly-iasyncpolicy((system-net-http-httpresponsemessage)))))) from which you can retrieve any registered service. (*It also passes the request as a parameter.*)

```
services.AddHttpClient<IMySuperHttpClient, MySuperHttpClient>()
        .AddPolicyHandler((provider, _) => MySuperHttpClient.GetRetryPolicy(provider))
```

So, all you need to do is to pass through the `IServiceProvider` down to your  `OnRetry` method

```
internal static IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> GetRetryPolicy(IServiceProvider provider)
=> HttpPolicyExtensions
        .HandleTransientHttpError()
        .OrResult(msg => msg.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(4,
            retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)),
            OnRetry(provider));
}
```

There is no such overload of `WaitAndRetryAsync` where the `onRetry` delegate anticipates an `IServiceProvider`. We need to introduce a helper method like this:

```
private static Action<DelegateResult<HttpResponseMessage>, TimeSpan> OnRetry(IServiceProvider provider)
    => (dr, ts) => OnRetry(dr, ts, provider);

private static void OnRetry(DelegateResult<HttpResponseMessage> delegateResult, TimeSpan timespan, IServiceProvider provider)
{
    // var logger = ??
    // logger.LogWarning($"API call failed blah blah.");
}
```

- The first `OnRetry` receives an `IServiceProvider` and returns an `Action<DelegateResult<HttpResponseMessage>, TimeSpan>`

  - The returned method is a good delegate for the `WaitAndRetryAsync`'s `onRetry`
- The second `OnRetry` is the same yours, I've just replaced your context parameter to the provider

So, basically the first `OnRetry` acts as an adapter between the `WaitAndRetryAsync` and the second `OnRetry` to pass through the `provider`.