# Cannot get Polly retry Http calls when given exceptions are raised

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, dotnet-httpclient, polly, httpclientfactory

My service definition:

```
var host = new HostBuilder().ConfigureServices(services =>
{
    services
        .AddHttpClient<Downloader>()
        .AddPolicyHandler((services, request) =>
            HttpPolicyExtensions
            .HandleTransientHttpError()
            .Or<SocketException>()
            .Or<HttpRequestException>()
            .WaitAndRetryAsync(
                new[] { TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) },
                onRetry: (outcome, timespan, retryAttempt, context) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Delaying {timespan}, retrying {retryAttempt}.");
                }));

    services.AddTransient<Downloader>();

}).Build();
```

Implementation of the `Downloader`:

```
class Downloader
{
    private HttpClient _client;
    public Downloader(IHttpClientFactory factory)
    {
        _client = factory.CreateClient();
    }

    public Download()
    {
        await _client.GetAsync(new Uri("localhost:8800")); // A port that no application is listening
    }
}
```

With this setup, I expect to see three attempts of querying the endpoint, with the logging message printed to the console (I've also unsuccessfully tried with a logger, using the console for simplicity here).

Instead of the debugging messages, I see the unhandled exception message (which I only expect to see after the retries and the printed logs).

> Unhandled exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (127.0.0.1:8800)
> ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10061): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Comment: HandleTransientHttpError catches HttpRequestException so you don't need an Or clause for this. Also the Or<SocketException> is unnecessary since it is an inner exception.

Comment: True, I did actually add them to be on the safer side, though regardless, I cannot see the logging messages. I also tried very radical waits (e.g., tens of `600` seconds and increased the client's timeout accordingly) that obviously will be a noticeable wait; I did not notice that long wait! :) It quickly throws the exception on the console and exits.

Comment: Tomorrow I will try to reproduce it on my machine and let you know how to fix it. At quick glance I can not spot the root cause.

Comment: thanks, I'd appreciate that.

Comment: Interestingly removing `services.AddTransient<Downloader>();` it seems if it is kept, the instance will get a different client than the one configured with poly (https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclientfactory-named-typed-clients-aspnetcore), also changing `Downloader(IHttpClientFactory` to `Downloader(HttpClient` fixes the issue. I am a bit confused since most examples on MSFT docs use client factory. Though I'm happy to proven wrong and shown the error is somewhere else.

Comment: Yepp, you have found the root cause. I've posted an answer where I have detailed why it caused the problem. I've also tried to give clarity around the different HttpClient types.

Comment: BTW: Why couldn't you access the Logger? [This SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52946079/how-to-log-retries-from-polly-with-iloggerfactory/73127538#73127538) details how to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Some clarification around HttpClient types

You can register several different pre-configured `HttpClient`s into the DI system:

- **Named client**: It is a named, pre-configured `HttpClient` which can be accessed through `IHttpClientFactory`'s `Create` method
- **Typed client**: It is a pre-configured wrapper around `HttpClient` which can be accessed through either the `ITypedHttpClientFactory` or through the wrapper interface
- **Named, Typed client**: It is a named, pre-configured wrapper around `HttpClient` which can be accessed through `IHttpClientFactory` and `ITypedHttpClientFactory`

#### The `AddHttpClient` extension method

This method tries to register Factories as singletons and Concrete types as transient objects. *[Here you can find the related source code.](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/215b39abf947da7a40b0cb137eab4bceb24ad3e3/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DependencyInjection/HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.cs)* So, you don't need to register the concrete types either as Transient or as Scoped by yourself.

#### Named clients

You can register a named client via the `AddHttpClient` by providing a unique name

```
services.AddHttpClient("UniqueName", client => client.BaseAdress = ...);
```

You can access the registered client via the `IHttpClientFactory`

```
private readonly HttpClient uniqueClient;
public XYZService(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
  => uniqueClient = clientFactory.CreateClient("UniqueName");
```

#### `CreateClient` call without name

If you call the `CreateClient` without name it will create a new `HttpClient` which is not pre-configured. More precisely it is not pre-configured by you rather by the framework itself with some default setup.

**That's the root cause of your issue, that you have created a `HttpClient` which is not decorated with the policies.**

#### Typed client

You can register a typed client via the `AddHttpClient<TClient>` or through the `AddHttpClient<TClient, TImplementation>` [overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientfactoryservicecollectionextensions.addhttpclient?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

```
services.AddHttpClient<UniqueClient>(client => client.BaseAdress = ...);
services.AddHttpClient<IUniqueClient, UniqueClient>(client => client.BaseAdress = ...);
```

The former can be accessed through the `ITypedHttpClientFactory`

```
private readonly UniqueClient uniqueClient;
public XYZService(ITypedHttpClientFactory<UniqueClient> clientFactory)
  => uniqueClient = clientFactory.CreateClient(new HttpClient());
```

The later can be accessed through the typed client's interface

```
private readonly IUniqueClient uniqueClient;
public XYZService(IUniqueClient client)
  => uniqueClient = client;
```

The implementation class (`UniqueClient`) in both cases should receive an `HttpClient` as a parameter

```
private readonly HttpClient httpClient;
public UniqueClient(HttpClient client)
  => httpClient = client;
```

#### Named and Typed clients

As you could spot I've called the `ITypedHttpClientFactory<UniqueClient>`'s `CreateClient` method with a new `HttpClient`. (*Side note: I could also call it with the `clientFactory.CreateClient()`*).

But it does not have to be a default `HttpClient`. You can retrieve a named client as well. In that case you would have a named, typed client.

[In this SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58438204/proper-way-to-handle-multiple-services-with-polly-circuit-breaker/73539024#73539024) I've demonstrated how to use this technique to register the same Circuit Breaker decorated typed clients multiple times for different domains.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating on that.